# AngularJS with .net core model not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have been learning some .net core and I am building an API with it. Normally I would work with angular and send requests there.

I have the following angular snippet:

```
//The data I need to send.
$scope.PersonalInfo = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    companyName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    imageLink: ''
};
```

Then there's the backend model for the same data:

```
public class UserProfileModel
{

    public string userID { get; set; }

    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public string companyName { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }

    public string confirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string imageLink { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the method that should send it:

```
$scope.UpdateProfile = function () {

    var profile = JSON.stringify($scope.PersonalInfo);

    $http.post('/api/Profile/Users', profile).then(function (response) {
        debugger;
        $log.log(profile);
        $log.log(response);
    });
};
```

No matter how many changes I have done, (send the data as a stringified JSON, or send the scoped object), when the request hits the controller, I end up with this:

[image: Model not being bound...]

$scope.PersonalInfo is full of data before the request is sent.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to stringify the JS object before sending it (this is done automatically by `$http`). Have you tried it without the stringification?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't bind with or without it.

Comment: make your C# UserProfileModel in PascalCase ... UserId, FirstName etc... This probably has to do with the JSON Serializer settings.

Comment: Can you add  `userId: ''` to `PersonalInfo` and see if that works, it may be looking for all properties.

Comment: Do you know how to use Google Chrome's network traffic tool to check the requests/responses?

Comment: Switching to pascal case and adding userID fixed nothing so far. I actually switched from pascal case to try to fix it. I will look into the request which I have not checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mention [FromBody] attribute in your post call. Like So,

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/bar/users")]
    public IActionResult Users([FromBody]UserProfileViewModel profile)
    {

        return Json(new { Data = profile });
    }
```

That should do it.

The necessity to use the `FromBody` attribute is so that the framework can use the correct `input formatter` to model bind. The default formatter used, for example, with content type application/json is the JSON formatter based on Json.Net

Detailed information at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

Comment: Great, that worked very well. If I may ask. Why is it necessary to add the annotation for it to do it this way now? It used to accept data from the Request's body by default before.

Comment: Hi Muqeet Khan, i tried using FromBody also but not binding data in our model, so any other way to bind data

Comment: Hi Durga Siva, .Net Core now requires the content type of json to be sent by your request or otherwise won't accept it either.